# dataTable, add row button when using serverside processing

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

I use server side processing files from the download as starting point with the ssp.class.php file. All works fine, but not the button. In the last column, I want to add some buttons. A lot to be found about this, but not working for me because I defined column data in php and not js. I can't put a function inside the column array like in the js examples. 
I have the following code running:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    pageSetUp();

    var table = $('#dt_basic').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "index.php?loc=client/clients"
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    public function clients() {
        $columns = array(
            array( 'db' => 'id',       'dt' => 0 ),
            array( 'db' => 'name',     'dt' => 1 ),
            array( 'db' => 'address',  'dt' => 2 ),
            array( 'db' => 'telephone', 'dt' => 3 ),
        );

        $table = 'clients';
        $primaryKey = 'id';
        $sql_details = array(
            'user' => #####,
            'pass' => #####,
            'db'   => #####,
            'host' => #####
        );

        echo json_encode(
            SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
        );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Review datatables options, you can manipulate buttons by javascript after datatables  initialize https://datatables.net/reference/option/

Comment: Have you tried to pass column value as string?
ex: `'host' => '<button>DisplayName</button>'`